# How to write the model default function correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to write the model default function correctly?

I have a `TestDefalt` model, and its default function:

```
def genefunc(instance, detail):

    str = instance.name + "/abc/"

    return str

class TestDefalt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    detail = models.CharField(default=genefunc, max_length=11)
```

And in my serializers and views:

```
# serializer
class TestDefaultSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestDefalt
        fields = "__all__"

# view
class TestDCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestDefaultSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = TestDefalt.objects.all()
```

When I access the `TestDCreateAPIView`, I get bellow error:

```
TypeError at /test04/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `TestDefalt.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `TestDefalt.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the TestDefaultSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
...

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 782, in get_default
    return self._get_default()
TypeError: genefunc() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'instance' and 'detail'
```

Comment: default parameter function doesn't take any argument. Please reconsider your approach.

Comment: Are you confusing the default function with the upload_to function on a FileField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value for a field's `default` is a callable, it's called without any argument, so your solution won't work. The proper solution here is to override the `save()` method:

```
class TestDefalt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    detail = models.CharField(default='', max_length=11)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if not self.pk and not self.detail:
            self.detail = self.name + "whatever"
        return super(TestDefalt).save(*args, **kw)
```

Note that if  `len(self.name) == 11`, `len(self.name + "something")` will be > 11, so you probably want to set a greater `maxlength` for `detail`.